# Where no observer exists, does this mean the wavefunction never collapses?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, measurement-problem, wavefunction-collapse

In most places across the universe, there is no conceivably sentient candidate to act as an "observer" to this system.

Are we to believe that, in the emptiness of intergalactic space, or deep inside a star like the sun, for billions of billions of years, **no collapse of the wavefunction of this system has ever occurred**?

If not, then in these systems where no conceivable observers can exist, then any occurring "collapse" must be an inherently internal process describable by the usual wavefunction evolution, without any magical collapse condition called "measurement"?

Has it been tried that there is absolutely no way to insert a measuring instrument, eg. a traveling photon, to insert this ad hoc into the wavefunction of the system and then checking how this affects the evolution of this system, hopefully resulting in a clean spike "collapse" due to this photon hitting the system?

Comment: In epistemic interpretations of QM, the wave function is not a property of the system but a representation of an agent's (read: scientist's) knowledge of the system, or at least a way to formalize the probabilities of outcomes of experiments. From that perspective, there's nothing wrong with no collapse occurring when then there is no human.

Comment: This may help - [Parallel Worlds Probably Exist. Here’s Why](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTXTPe3wahc)

Answer (score 2):

The wavefunction of an isolated system "collapses" whenever interaction causes it to become entangled with another system. If the entire universe is the system, there is nothing else  to interact with, and no "collapse".

Comment: how does this reconcile with us, a tiny part of this universal wavefunction, making a measurement and collapsing a small "electron" in the universe?

Comment: small suggestion: maybe instead of "entangled with another system," one should write "entangled with another *large* system"? Two electrons can be put into an entangled state without leading to decoherence.

Comment: @Andrew. I'm not sure that I agree. In Mott's argument (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mott_problem) for the existence of cloud-chamber tracks he shows that an s-wave electron can only ionize two atoms if they and the origin lie on one  straight line. The interaction of the electron  with the first atom has therefore effectively "collapsed" the wavefunction from spherical symmetry to a linear momentum  eigenstate.

Comment: It seems to me that if you take the point of view that collapse occurs any time you entangle two systems, then anytime you prepare a Bell state by (say) entangling two photons, you would collapse the wave function. Maybe that is a self-consistent point of view, but it seems extreme to me.

Comment: @Andrew. I suppose that is why I write "collapse" with the scare quotes.  I don't think it a well defined concept, but at the same time it a useful approximation. I guess that I am a "many worlder"

Comment: In some treatments of the [quantum-to-classical transition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence#Loss_of_interference_and_the_transition_from_quantum_to_classical_probabilities), one often assumes that the possible states of the environment after interacting with the quantum system are orthogonal, which in general relies on assuming the environment is large. ([einselection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einselection)). However, I also agree with you that "the moment of collapse" isn't well defined, and I agree entanglement with an external system is part of the story, so +1.